# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined using Onsen and webDB

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, web-sql

How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined using Onsen and webDB, i am trying to fix errors.

Here is some of the codes:

```
function getItems(){

    db.transaction(function(tx){
    // table name items
     tx.exectuteSql('SELECT * FROM items', [], renderItems, onErrors);
        });


function renderItems(tx, rs)


{
    var output=" ";
    // <ons-list id="ShoppingL">

    var list = document.getElementById('ShoppingL');
    for(i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++)
    {

        var row = rs.rows.item(i)
        output += "<ons-list-item>"+ row.item +
        "<div class=\"right\"> <ons-button ><ons-icon icon=\" trash\"></ons-icon></ons-button></div>"+
        "</ons-list-item>";
    }
    list.innerHTML=output;
}
```

The following error occurs:

I got the code from a tutorial code some while ago from a website,  everything seems logical but I get the following errors were displayed by chrome browser:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
app.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
    at getItems (test.js:66)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (test.js:20)
    at Object.util$1.triggerElementEvent (util.js:337)
    at ons-page.js:253
    at setImmediate.js:48
    at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:66)
    at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:112)
getItems @ test.js:66
(anonymous) @ test.js:20
util$1.triggerElementEvent @ util.js:337
(anonymous) @ ons-page.js:253
(anonymous) @ setImmediate.js:48
runIfPresent @ setImmediate.js:66
onGlobalMessage @ setImmediate.js:112
9index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: AddItem is not defined
    at HTMLElement.onclick (index.html:1)
```

Comment: Welcome SO. Don't just dump your entire code; please try to limit down to include just the relevant code. Also, have a look at improving the mark-down in your question as I think you've got code blocks enclosed in quote blocks or something going on.

Comment: Looks like some javaScript file is missing, or not referenced.

Comment: all the files are available but i was told not to dump the whole code.

Comment: where is `db` defined in your code?